# How do I update EntityFramework in most elegant way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here's my model - two tables Contacts and Companies. Contacts are bound to each Company with their Company_ID property And I use EntityFramework.

When I want to add contacts to a company, I go through the ones I want to add and change their Company_ID property to the Company_ID of the company I want to add them into.

But then it doesn't update the Contacts in that Company, they are the same old ones unless I do the following:

```
Context.Dispose();
Context = new CompanyContactsEntity();
```

But this is not efficient as I just want to update the current instance and NOT create a new one.

Comment: Try `Context.SaveChanges()`!

Comment: did it. If I change something in the Company it works, but if it's the Contacts - it does not load them in the company...

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid assigning the Identifiers. try to assign the entity reference instead.
For instance:

```
Company company = ...//look-up/cerate for your company, etc.
Contact contact = ...//look-up/create for the contact
contact.Company = company; // Assign an instance reference but not the ID
```